# Special Characters in Regex Brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I want to match one of the following characters: `a`, `b`, `c`, or `+` (in JavaScript). Do I need to escape the `+`? Is it `/[abc+]/` or `/[abc\+]/`? Both work in my limited selection of test browsers. Which is (more) correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Regex reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Under character classes:

> Any character except `^-]\` add that
>   character to the possible matches for
>   the character class.

In other words, you don't have to escape the `+`.

Comment: Or `?`,`*` and `.` which a lot of people (including myself) often seem to do out of habit as well.

Answer (score 2):

No need to escape the `+` in character class `[xxx]`:

```
/[abc+]/
```